# R - time series reduction with plot for multiple columns

Tags: r, time-series

I've got data, in which measurement of MV_1, MV_2, MV_3 ..., MV_40 variable was made every 5 minutes. Now I have to aggregate this for each hour and make a time_series plot (for each variable should be separate plot - changes of variable in time). Type of the data like below (just small part - there were more than 1000 time points).

```
date                MV_1 MV_2
2017-07-08 01:19:37 212 163
2017-07-08 01:24:41 222 162
2017-07-08 01:29:37 207 162
2017-07-08 01:34:41 189 161
2017-07-08 01:39:37 220 161
2017-07-08 01:44:41 186 16
2017-07-08 01:49:37 193 16
2017-07-08 01:54:40 186 159
2017-07-08 01:59:37 194 159
2017-07-08 02:04:40 193 159
2017-07-08 02:09:37 183 159
2017-07-08 02:14:40 215 158
2017-07-08 02:19:37 213 158
2017-07-08 02:24:40 209 157
```

First column contain data with hours in POSIXct format (%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%S format), second and third is numeric.

For aggregate this type for one-hour average measurement (it mus be average), I've done like below

```
aggregate(my_data[MV_1], list(hour=cut(as.POSIXct(my_data$date)-1, "hour")), mean)
```

Then plot. And this for all the columns (MV_2, MV_3 etc).

But is there a way to do it more simply and automate the process?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data frame `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
DF$date <- as.POSIXct(DF$date)
hour <- as.POSIXct(trunc(DF$date, "hour"))
avg <- aggregate(DF[-1], data.frame(hour), mean)

avg
##                  hour  MV_1     MV_2
## 1 2017-07-08 01:00:00 201.0 128.7778
## 2 2017-07-08 02:00:00 202.6 158.2000

matplot(avg[[1]], avg[-1], type = "l", xaxt = "n")
Axis(DF[[1]], side = 1)
```

### zoo

Or to use a time series representation convert to zoo, use aggregate.zoo and plot using classic or ggplot2 graphics as shown.  These plots graph each series on the same plot.  If you want separate plots omit `screen=1` and `facet=NULL` respectively.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF)
hour <- as.POSIXct(trunc(time(z), "hour"))
zavg <- aggregate(z, hour, mean)
zavg
##                      MV_1     MV_2
## 2017-07-08 01:00:00 201.0 128.7778
## 2017-07-08 02:00:00 202.6 158.2000

# classic graphics
plot(zavg, screen = 1)

# or ggplot2 graphics
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(zavg, facet = NULL)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "date                MV_1 MV_2
2017-07-08 01:19:37 212 163
2017-07-08 01:24:41 222 162
2017-07-08 01:29:37 207 162
2017-07-08 01:34:41 189 161
2017-07-08 01:39:37 220 161
2017-07-08 01:44:41 186 16
2017-07-08 01:49:37 193 16
2017-07-08 01:54:40 186 159
2017-07-08 01:59:37 194 159
2017-07-08 02:04:40 193 159
2017-07-08 02:09:37 183 159
2017-07-08 02:14:40 215 158
2017-07-08 02:19:37 213 158
2017-07-08 02:24:40 209 157"
L <- trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines)))
L <- gsub(" +", ",", L)
L <- sub(",", " ", L)
L[1] <- sub(" ", ",", L[1])
DF <- read.csv(text = L)
```

Comment: @ Thank! Just one more questio - how should I modify the code to obtain completely separate plots (I need to save them later as separate .jpg file) - if I omit `screen=1` or `facet = NULL` there for separate series but still on one screen.

Comment: ` pdf(); for(i in 1:ncol(zavg)) plot(zavg[, i], ylab = names(zavg)[i]); dev.off()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` and `lubridate`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(hour = floor_date(date, unit = "hour")) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(contains("MV")), funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  melt(id = "hour") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid( ~ variable) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot1]

Or if you decide to have all time-series in one plot:

```
df %>%
  group_by(hour = floor_date(date, unit = "hour")) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(contains("MV")), funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  melt(id = "hour") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot2]

Comment: thanks a lot! and the same question as above - is there a simple way to force generate completely separate plots (from the one-series plot, not multi-series - there are just ready) in order to save them later in separate /jpg files?